# Drag and Drop functionality in Office Add-in

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, office365-apps

I implemented drag and drop text from email message body to office add-in. It is working in Outlook Desktop client but it is not working when running the add-in from OWA. it is not detecting the drop zone. Is there any additional configuration that needs to be done or is it not possible because of browser cross Iframe security rules?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur so it is currently not supported. Any update on when this will be supported? there are multiple requests from 4 years ago on the user voice https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins?query=drag